# How to get Hoptoad or Airbrake Error Notification in Development Environment on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling, ruby-on-rails-plugins, hoptoad

Please any one help to solve, how to get hoptoad/airbrake Error Notification in Development Environment on Rails,

I have configured the airbrake correctly, and even I am getting test mail from airbrake i.e. by running `rake hoptoad:test` or `rake airbrake:test`

but other then that i dont get anything, i.e. errors, expections, etc.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following to your `config/environments/development.rb`:

```
config.action_controller.consider_all_requests_local = false
```

And access your application through your non-loopback IP (not `http://localhost:3000/` or `http://127.0.0.1:3000/`), e.g. `http://192.168.1.3:3000/` (look for correct IP in your network settings).

Answer (score 6):

I think the answer here should be get 'development' out of your config. Try the following line in an initializer:

```
HoptoadNotifier.configuration.development_environments = ['cucumber', 'test']
```

or

```
Airbrake.configure do |config|
  config.development_environments = %w(cucumber test)
end
```